# Appending GET parameters to URL from <form> action

Tags: php, forms, search, parameters, get

So say I'm currently on index.php or index.php?p=about within my current web build.

I am trying to build a search form that will be displayed on most pages, but I want the form action to go to http://mywebsiteurl.com/?p=search&q=GETDATA, as my website's paging depends on the data passed to the 'p' attribute.

How would I append the search parameter to the URL in a static fashion, upon submission?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
  <form method="get" action="index.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="p" value="search" />
     <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
     <input type="submit" value="search" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the value of the parameter `p` inside a hidden form field inside the search form; something like:

```
<input type="hidden"
    name="p"
    value="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["p"])); ?>" />
```

It's not a good idea to put the parameter to the form action parameter; post requests are handled differently than GET requests, the values in a POST request aren't appended to the URL by ? and & as with GET; meaning that you wouldn't actually get the p parameter into the script handling the POST request from the form...

Also take care not to show the request parameter unreflected (hence the htmlspecialchars, thanks for the hint!), since malicious clients could try to inject code into your page ([HTML injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) / [XSS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Scripting)).

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: you're right, I'll correct that immediately, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Could someone breifly explain the XSS vulnerability? I'll research it further relating to my situation

Comment: It's generally XSS vulnerable when you show parameters unreflected, just as they come from the client; that way they might inject HTML code into your site.

Comment: So as the search form would only lead to p=search, it could be static:
<input type="hidden" value="search" name="p" />

Comment: if the value of p does not change, why do you even need to transmit it?

Comment: p refers to page, so when someone submits a search form, it takes them to p=search, while passing the query data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field in your form to maintain the value of the `p` parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="p" 
       value="<?= htmlentities($_GET['p'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
```

Comment: Good comment. Changed sample code to use _GET instead. In practice I imagine the value of p would be likely to be written by the application rather than blindly copied.

Comment: its still vulnerable you should use `<input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?= htmlentities($_GET['p'],ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />` have a look at http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting.htm

Comment: Thank-you for the advice (and article). Fixed code sample accordingly.