# Add a second variable to variable generated when submitting a form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've done some research on StackOverflow but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a form with an input that when a vehicle's registration number is submitted, it provides me with the vehicle's information on the same page. This I get to work.

After submission my URL will look like this:
site.com/admin.php?asset_reg_no=CN1001

But the problem that I'm having is that I use page hooks. This means that I use a static page (admin.php) to display my site and the content of the page is updated according to the page name in the url e.g. admin.php?page=search or admin.php?page=reports.

I want to add the 2 variables when submitting my web form. It would look like this in the step process:

1. Opening page: site.com?page=search
2. After form submission: site.com?page=search&asset_reg_no=CN1001

This is my current PHP page:

```
$results_searchResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['asset_reg_no'])) {
  $results_searchResults = $_GET['asset_reg_no'];
}

// Database query
$query_searchResults = sprintf("SELECT ft_asset_make.make_desc, ft_asset_type.type_name, ft_asset.* FROM ft_asset INNER JOIN ft_asset_make ON ft_asset.make_ID = ft_asset_make.ID INNER JOIN ft_asset_type ON ft_asset.asset_type_ID = ft_asset_type.ID WHERE asset_reg_No = %s", GetSQLValueString($results_searchResults, "text"));

$searchResults = mysql_query($query_searchResults, $ft_connect) or die(mysql_error());

$row_searchResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResults);
$totalRows_searchResults = mysql_num_rows($searchResults);
```

Comment: Have a hidden input with the value from `$_GET['asset_reg_no']`...

Comment: (Or if I misunderstood, have a hidden input with the other value - but the idea stays the same)

Comment: Post the HTML code of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside your search form tags

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="search">
```

Alternatively, you could change the forms action value, but that can get weird and may not work at all.

Comment: I did just that. With a little bit of research I came upon the exact same solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476602/appending-get-parameters-to-url-from-form-action

Answer (score 0):

Check for current hook and pass an hidden variable in form.
for example:

```
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='page' value='".$_GET['page']."' />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After your SQL query you can return to the static page with **header**, including the parameters you want :

```
<?php
// SQL QUERIES HERE.
header( "Location: site.com?page=search&asset_reg_no=CN1001" ); // NOTICE DE PARAMETERS.
?>
```

This is our imaginary static page :

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET[ "page" ] ) )
     echo "Page = " . $_GET[ "page" ];
else echo "No page";

echo "<br/>";

if ( isset( $_GET[ "asset_reg_no" ] ) )
     echo "Data = " . $_GET[ "asset_reg_no" ];
else echo "No data";
?>
```